# d-bus administration

Tags: linux, qt, embedded, dbus

I have created simple application using d-bus, it works on kubuntu but doesn't work on my embedded linux.

When I run a qt application it says: **Not connected to D-Bus server**

When I try to run dbus-monitor I got this error:

> Failed to open connection to session bus: /usr/bin/dbus-launch
> terminated abnormally with the following error: Autolaunch requested,
> but X11 support not compiled in. Cannot continue.

dbus-daemon process is running on my system but dbus-launch is not.
I presume that dbus-launch have to be running because it run on my kubunutu.

Can any one suggest me anything?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, and I solved it like suggested [here](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/dbus/2009-September/011754.html).

If you have a program named `app`, then what worked for me is this :

```
eval `dbus-launch --auto-syntax` ./app
```

Comment: It may be better form to put a script that starts dbus globally somewhere in your `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d` folder. That way dbus is launched and starts running after the Xorg starts. See [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/init#Dbus)