# Scan ports with dbus-launch returns X11 error

Tags: linux, serial-port, dbus

I am trying to scan the serial ports of my PC with the rust library serialport.

```rust
let ports = serialport::available_ports().expect("No ports found!");
```

I got the error:

```
Unable to acquire session bus: Error spawning command line “dbus-launch --autolaunch=b011d47b863648d5b0184ff29026a949 --binary-syntax --close-stderr”: Child process exited with code 1
```

When running the dbus-launch command by myself I get this message:

```
Autolaunch requested, but X11 support not compiled in. Cannot continue.
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104111/d-bus-administration) post but the solution didn't work for me.